# My myIndexOf method won't return the right int.

Tags: list, indexing

I'm trying to create a myIndexOf() method that returns the index integer that the element is at on the list. Example: List = Mark Bob Sam; Call myIndexOf(Bob); returns 1. However, I can't get my method to return the correct variable and I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. This is what I have so far; thanks for the help!

```
  public int myIndexOf(T element) {


    for(int i = 0; i< rear; i++){

        if(element == list[i]){

            return i;
        }

    }


    return NOT_FOUND;


  }
```

Comment: What is "the right int"?

Comment: Sorry terrible title; Ex. My list = Bob, Sam, George, Eric. Call myIndexOf(Sam); it will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

If it's returning 1, it's returning the right int, since lists, like arrays, have zero-based indexes. They start at position 0, so Bob = 0, Sam = 1, George = 2 and Eric = 3, even through a count() or length() would otherwise return 4 (elements, which is also correct).

If you really need to return a int based on a one-based list, simply add +1 to myIndexOf(Element). Just be sure not to use this int when refering back to the list, since it would end returning Index out of Range errors.